# How to delete regex match text in emacs?

Tags: regex, emacs

How can I delete some text  that match with a regex in emacs?

I suppose that using:

`'(query-replace-regexp PATTERN EMPTY)`

and:

`'(replace-regexp PATTERN EMPTY)`

but they throw:

`perform-replace: Invalid regexp: "Premature end of regular expression".`

Comment: Need more information.  Emacs is telling you that your regular expression has a syntax error.  Perhaps an unbalanced grouping paren?  Or unmatched `[`?

Comment: Paste the regular expression that you're using.

Answer (score 13):

In general, you can delete text that matches a given regexp by using the empty string `""` as the replacement in the two functions you mention. However, as others mentioned in the comments above, your regular expression is faulty.

For instance, if your buffer contains the following text:

```
1. My todo list
1.1. Brush teeth
1.2. Floss
2. My favorite movies
2.1. Star Wars episodes 4-6
```

and you would like to get rid of the numbers at the beginning of each line, you could place the cursor at the beginning of the buffer and then type `M-C-%` (that is, you press at a time: ALT, CTRL, Shift, 5) to invoke the command `query-replace-regexp`. You'll get asked two parameters in the minibuffer, first the regexp to match than the replacement string.
So, in our example, you could use the following regexp:

```
\([0-9]\.\)+\s-
```

as the first parameter, and simply hit ENTER for the second parameter, i.e., don't specify anything as the replacement. That way, the replacement is the empty string: you replace what ever matches the regexp with nothing.

`query-replace-regexp` will ask you interactively for every match if you want to replace it or if you want to skip it. This is the "query"-part in `query-replace-regexp` and it is helpful to see if the regexp you came up with actually matches what you thought it does. If you're sure it does, you can type `!` to make Emacs replace the remaining matches without asking every time.

If you use `M-x replace-regexp` instead of `M-C-%` Emacs will replace every match without asking for input at every match.

For the special case that you'd like to delete whole lines when a certain part of the line matches a regexp, there's also `delete-matching-lines` and its evil, goatee-wearing twin brother from a parallel universe `delete-non-matching-lines`.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you very much for your reply.
I don't want to delete whole line which matches with regex. I want to delete only the matching substring.
For example, given <code>'this is a whole line'</code> and my regex to match is <code>/l/</code>, I expect this <code>'this is a whoe ine'</code>, in other words, I want to replace all matched substring with an empty string.

Comment: Hi, NeoRiddle. I've extended my answer to explain in more detail how to do what you want to do. (P.S.: Use backticks instead of "<code>" to format code segments in comments on stackoverflow.) To replace the `l` in `this is a line`, place the cursor before the line and type `M-C-% l ENTER ENTER` and then `y` when asked interactively to replace the l with the empty string.

Comment: I think you're mixing up sed/perl etc syntax with regular expressions. The regular expression `l` is expressed as `/l/` in perl and sed, but as `"l"` in Emacs lisp, or just `l` interactively.

Comment: loving the evil brother, helped me out a tonne! `delete-non-matching-lines`

Comment: @pjammer The evil brother loves you too!